# Invalid signature with Bittrex API calls in C#

Tags: c#, api, signature, hmac

I am trying to access my wallet balances in Bittrex via Bittrex's API calls, but for some reason I'm getting response message saying `INVALID_SIGNATURE`.

I use these functions to create the signature:

**GetNonce**

```
private String GetNonce()
{
    long ms = (long)((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);

    return ms.ToString();
}
```

**GetApiSignature**

```
private String GetApiSignature(String key, String message)
{
    using (var hmacsha512 = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)))
    {
        hmacsha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        return string.Concat(hmacsha512.Hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")).ToArray());
    }       
}
```

Here's how I "compile" my calls:

```
public String ApiQuery(String requestUrl)
{

    url = new Uri(requestUrl);
    webreq = WebRequest.Create(url);

    signature = GetApiSignature(apiSecret, requestUrl);
    webreq.Headers.Add("apisign", signature );

    webresp = webreq.GetResponse();
    stream = webresp.GetResponseStream();
    strRead = new StreamReader(stream);

    String rtn = strRead.ReadToEnd();

    return rtn;
}
```

I am getting a the same signature as the [python API wrapper](https://github.com/ericsomdahl/python-bittrex/blob/master/bittrex/bittrex.py) does with the same `url` and `nonce` etc., but cannot access my balances. When I do a call that doesn't require any signatures, it works just fine... Not sure at all what I'm doing wrong with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got the answer from elsewhere. Looks like my encoding was wrong, and it didn't work because of that (though I thought I tried other encoders...).

The correct encoding is ASCII, whereas I used UTF-8.

Here's the function I got:

```
private string genHMAC(string secret, string url)
{
    var hmac = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret));
    var messagebyte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url);
    var hashmessage = hmac.ComputeHash(messagebyte);
    var sign = BitConverter.ToString(hashmessage).Replace("-", "");

    return sign;
}
```

The problem is now solved and everything works as it should. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this function it is working fine for me and tested.

function calculateSign(url){
    var sign=crypto.createHmac('sha512',constants.bittrexCredentials.SECRET);

```
sign = sign.update(url,'ascii');
sign = sign.digest('hex');
return sign;
```

}
Full Implementation repo : https://github.com/tarun1475/Nodejs-Bittrex-Client